# What is the range of values in the numpy array returned from gdal ReadAsArray?

Tags: python, numpy, gdal

I downloaded the BigEarthNet dataset and I read the TIFF images in python with gdal. Code below. The resulting array had values far above the 0-255 range I was expecting, so what is the range of the values?

```
band1 = imagePath + "/" + img + "/" + img + "_B02.tif"
band_ds = gdal.Open(band1,  gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
raster_band = band_ds.GetRasterBand(1)
blue = raster_band.ReadAsArray()
print(blue)
```

This is the output

```
[[284 388 554 ... 325 318 325]

 [211 213 297 ... 319 300 318]

 [227 206 245 ... 305 318 332]

 ...

 [309 612 920 ... 710 643 554]

 [259 626 862 ... 654 646 536]

 [260 608 730 ... 501 629 526]]
```

Comment: The range goes from `blue.min()` to `blue.max()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen as you already have gdal installed by the looks,

```
gdalinfo <filename>
```

will give you the stats on your file which will include the max and min of the values stored . The data in a tif can represent many things, for example a DEM stores values representing height in the raster band.

The actual possible range of values depends on the datatype used to encode it. For example uint16 has a range of 0-65535 which I think I used in BIL format before.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about gdalinfo

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly a Numpy array you can get the max/min value with:

```
numpy.amax(raster_band)
numpy.amin(raster_band)
```

Comment: ... yes but if it's not a numpy friendly object at all it won't.... I just meant it could be something like a GDAL object which numpy wouldn't know how to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

[From the sentinel-2 user guide](https://sentinel.esa.int/web/sentinel/user-guides/sentinel-2-msi/resolutions/radiometric):

> Radiometric resolution is routinely expressed as a bit number,
>   typically in the range of 8 to 16 bits. The radiometric resolution of
>   the MSI instrument is 12 bit, enabling the image to be acquired over a
>   range of 0 to 4095 potential light intensity values.